# Golang: gin: get base url

Tags: go, routes, go-gin

I want to print base url of my routes, if you see my comments **i mean** the thing before colon sign **:** . More specifically its should be the thing before **:** sign of `router.Run(":3000")` here.

[ So according to my commented code it should be **localhost**. I just want to print **localhost** ]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "r/p/routes"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    routes.X(router) // localhost:3000/getpens
    routes.Y(router) // localhost:3000/getpencils

    router.Use(cors.Default())
    fmt.Println("this is base path : "+router.BasePath())
    router.Run(":3000")
}
```

So here `X` and `Y` are two functions that return routes from routes package, my api is fine, response ok tested by **postman**. I just want to print the string before **:** sign

In my attempts, I tried using `router.BasePath()` . But that only prints */*

So please help me to do this

Comment: That is not the functionality of BasePath please see the documentation https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#RouterGroup.BasePath

Comment: @Shubham Srivastava I know that and I specifically asked what I wanted. I have read doc already

Comment: gin doesn't know about the hostname at that point because you haven't told it which interface it should serve on. It's whatever you pass to `router.Run()`.

Comment: @Oin 1) so how localhost is coming out? 2)if i dont use gin, is there anyway i can get that "localhost" printed on my console?